# SQLite query question

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have 1 table:

```
table tb1 (
    _id integer primary key autoincrement
    ,busnum text not null
    , servdate date not null
);
```

I need a query which will get me all entries which have a "servdate" for the current week (the week starts on monday.)

So for example:

if I run the query on wednesday the 24th novemeber, it will get me all entries for monday 22nd, tuesday 23rd and wednesday 24th.

If I ran the query on sunday 28th, it will get me all entries for the full week (mon - sun), starting monday 22nd - sunday 28th.

If I run the query on monday, then it will just get me all entries for that day.

Thanks in advance. (thanks to admin for formatting my question)

Comment: Please edit your question so that its not all within a code block

Comment: What happens if your run the query on Saturday? Do you want the entries for the week from Monday to Saturday inclusively, or you want next week from next Monday to next week's Sunday?

Comment: if you run query on saturday then it still lists for that week, same as the sunday example above. i.e, the query on saturday would return monday (of that week), and tue,wed,thurs,fri,sat, of that same week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modifier `weekday 1` (from [the date time functions documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)) :

```
WHERE servdate BETWEEN date('now', 'Weekday 1', '-7 days') AND date('now')
```

Comment: From your link: "The 'weekday' modifier advances the date *forward* to the next date where the weekday number is N. Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so forth." (emphasis added).  So, the beginning date needs to be a week earlier.

Comment: Hi Benoit, I tried: SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE servdate BETWEEN date('now', 'Weekday 1') AND date('now') -- it didnt return anything

Comment: so .. WHERE servdate BETWEEN date('now'-7, 'Weekday 1') AND date('now') ? this doesnt work :s, it returns more entries than i would expect